# How do I change the display of meetings?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

How do I remove the semicomma appearing between the organizer and the subject in the calendar in outlook? If that's not possible, is it possible to change it to another sign?

Thanks,

Comment: What have you researched or tried? As far as I know, you can't. That is how Outlook is programed to separate the fields of appointment displays in the calendar view.

Comment: I've googled and tried to get an answer from microsoft directly. I'm 99% sure you're correct, but my boss insists

Comment: Maybe an upgrade to Office 2013!! I'm not seeing things like that here.